# Iterating through an array/vector Matlab

Tags: matlab

First off, I do have to apologize, because I'm very sure that I'm simply making a simple mistake. I am making my first program in MatLab, and have been reading up on the relevant documentation, but simply still can't seem to solve my problem.

I am trying to implement the equation for information entropy in MatLab (I'm sure it probably already exists, but that's beside the point), but I am having issues with arrayfun as it seems to be calling entropySingle with no arguments.

I have the following functions in appropriately named files

```
function y = entropySingle(x)
y = x * log2(x);
end
```

and

```
function y = entropy(x)
if ~isvector(x)
    error('Input must be a vector');
end 
x = arrayfun(entropySingle, x);
y = sum(x);
end
```

and I'm calling `entropy([1/3 1/4 1/6 1/8 1/12 1/24]).` The error occurs on line 2 of entropySingle, but why is it being called with a null pointer? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [element wise multiplication](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com):

```
y = x .* log2(x);
```

Not using that small `.` before the multiplication tell matlab this is about matrix multiplication where it is not.

Also, don't use the name `entropy`. You are overwriting a built-in matlab function, and this just invites more trouble to your code and life in general.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code to name it something different and use .* instead, but I am still experiencing the same errors.

Comment: However, if I use an anonymous function, `@(x) x .* log2(x)`, then everything works fine.